# Three.js Object3D.applyMatrix() setting incorrect scale

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, three.js

Three.js r.71

I'm just getting into Three.js (awesome btw) but am having an issue. I am trying to stream geometry and position/scale/rotation changes between clients using Socket.io and NodeJS. On the server I store the JSON representation of the scene and stream object changes between clients.

When the object's matrix changes (position, scale, rotation), I stream the new matrix to the server and forward it to the other clients. On the other clients I call applyMatrix() with the streamed object (the source object's matrix).

The problem I ran into is that when calling applyMatrix(sourceMatrix), it seems to multiple the existing scale by the scale found in sourceMatrix. For example, when the current object has a scale of x: 2, y:1, z:1, and I apply a matrix with the same scale, after calling applyMatrix, the destination object's scale is x:4, y:1, z:1.

This seems like a bug to me, but wanted to double check.

```
// Client JS:
client.changeMatrix = function (object) {

    // Set the object's scale to x:2 y:1 z:1 then call this twice.

    var data = {uuid: object.uuid, matrix: object.matrix};
    socket.emit('object:changeMatrix', data);

};

socket.on('object:matrixChanged', function (data) {

    var cIdx = getChildIndex(data.uuid);

    if (cIdx >= 0) {
        scene.children[cIdx].applyMatrix(data.matrix);

        // At this point, the object's scale is incorrect

        ng3.viewport.updateSelectionHelper();
        ng3.viewport.refresh();
    }

});

// Server JS:
socket.on('object:changeMatrix', function (data) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('object:matrixChanged', data);

});
```

Comment: You do not understand what `applyMatrix()` is doing. Have a look at the source code for that method.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the pointer. I dug through the code a bit before, but I am really new to 3D rendering and didn't quite understand how the matrix was used. I think I have it working for now, although there may be a better solution

Comment: `applyMatrix( matrix )` applies the transform represented by the matrix to the existing transform -- it does not overwrite the existing transform.

Comment: If applyMatrix is not the correct method, is there a simple solution to this issue? Reapplying each element to the matrix seems a bit long winded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WestLangley is correct, I really did not understand what apply matrix is doing (and still don't quite know what it is used for).

I solved my problem by manually setting each element in the source matrix and calling decompose:

```
// Client JS:
socket.on('object:matrixChanged', function (data) {

    var cIdx = getChildIndex(data.uuid);
    var child = null;
    var key;

    if (cIdx >= 0) {
        child = scene.children[cIdx];

        for (key in child.matrix.elements) {
            if (child.matrix.elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                child.matrix.elements[key] = data.matrix.elements[key];
            }
        }

        child.matrix.decompose(child.position, child.quaternion, child.scale);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, once the server picks up the Matrix object, calling:

```
child.matrix.copy(data.matrix);
```

does no work. That's why I ended up setting each element manually.

Comment: `matrix.copy( newMatrix )` followed by `matrix.decompose()` should work.